# rails self-referential join association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on an API only rails app where I am trying to mimic social media features. Like send request to user, accept/reject request, chat with friends. By referring to this [screen-cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=comments), now I am able to add other users as friends.

Bellow is my User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
end
```

Bellow is Friendship model

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

And I have defined routes as bellow to access current user

```
  resources :users do
    resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

I can add friends as bellow

```
current_user = User.find(params[:user_id])
requesting_user = User.find(params[:req_user_id])
current_user.friends << requesting_user
```

Everything works fine till here.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve accepting/rejecting a request?

I tried as, having one more `FriendRequest` model and through that decide whether to add request as friend or not. But not able to do it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The FriendRequest model is a good option.

You could  also try to add a status to Friendship (request, accepted, etc) and define scopes in your models to filter requests or friends.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a flag to `Friendship` model - `accepted` boolean.
Then I would add default scope:

*../friendship.rb*

`default_scope where(accepted: true)`

For pending friends list, create scope:

*../user.rb*

`has_many :pending_firends, through: :friendship do
 def pending
   where("friendships.accepted = ?", false)
 end
end`

I would say that rejecting = removing friendship record. You can add another feature - blocked.

`current_user.friends`

`current_user.pending_firends`

But you want to be consist so use:

*../friendship.rb*

 `scope :accepted, where(accepted: true)
 scope :pending, where(accepted: false)`

*../user.rb*

`has_many :pending_firends, -> { pending }, through: :friendship
has_many :accepted_firends, -> { accepted }, through: :friendship`

It should work, I could make some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, I made a status column and storing 3 status as of now. -1 for pending, 0 for rejection and 1 for accepted. Default will be -1. But if I follow your way of consist code `scope :accepted, ->{ where(status: 1) }` and `has_many :pending_friends, -> { pending }, :through => :friendships` I am getting `Could not find the source association(s) "pending_friend" or :pending_friends in model Friendship` error.